# How to set custom scrollbar cursor style on Electron’s Chromium?

Tags: css, electron, chromium

Somehow, scrollbar ignores `default` cursor style and always displays `text` style.

```css
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  cursor: default;
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: light-grey;
  cursor: default;
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<textarea>








foo</textarea>
```